# Find a $C^1$ function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ strictly increasing such that $\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}: f'(x)=0\rbrace$ has measure $>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If anyone could help I would be very thankful.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem suggests that this search won't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question doesn't have much to do with Sard's theorem. In fact here is a $C^\infty$ function that does what you want: Let $E\subset \mathbb R$ be a closed nowhere dense set of positive measure. Then there exists $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that $g=0$ on $E$ and $g>0$ off of $E.$ Define

$$f(x) = \int_0^x g(t)\, dt.$$

Then $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R),$ $f$ is strictly increasing, and $f'=0$ on $E,$ a set of positive measure.